# How to append to a file using Scheme?

Tags: scheme, append, gimp, script-fu

I am using TinyScheme (actually Script-Fu in GIMP), and cannot find a good way to open a file and append a line of text to it.

I am trying to log some info to the file for debugging, and transcript-on doesn't seem to be implemented...

Right now I am scraping along by reading the entire file (one character at a time!), concatenating that into a string, concatenating my text to the end of that, then writing it all out to the file again.

There must be a better way!

Answer (score 3):

It's going to be something like

```
(open-file "myfile" (file-options append))
```

You want to look up the `file-options` function.

#### Update

Here's the [guile version](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/guile/guile_317.html):

```
(open-file "myfilename.dat" "a")
```

Comment: hmm... that gets me to the right part of the docs at least (:
GIMP doesn't recognize file-options, alas...

Comment: Try the open-file flag.  Unfortunately, it's very hard to axiomatize this stuff, so Scheme doesn't specify it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same exact problem in GIMP and decided to use `open-input-output-file`. My solution is something like this:

```
(let* ((out (open-input-output-file "file.txt") ))
  (display "hello world" out)
  (newline out)                    
  (close-output-port out))
```

Went through the TinyScheme source and checked that this function actually calls `fopen` with `"a+"`. The file is open for reading and writing. For our purposes we only want to write, so just ignore reading.

I am writing a Script-Fu to write the values of `gimp-selection-bounds` to a file.