# R5RS Scheme input-output: How to write/append text to an output file?

Tags: io, scheme, read-write, r5rs, meep

What is a simple way to output text to file in a R5RS compliant version of Scheme?
I use MIT's MEEP (which uses Scheme for scripting) and I want to output text to file. I have found the following other answers on Stackoverflow:

[File I/O operations - Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4181355/file-i-o-operations-scheme)

[How to append to a file using Scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/544812/how-to-append-to-a-file-using-scheme)

[Append string to existing textfile [sic] in IronScheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30393528/append-string-to-existing-textfile-in-ironscheme)

But, they weren't exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answers by Charlie Martin, Ben Rudgers, and Vijay Mathew were very helpful, but I would like to give an answer which is simple and easy to understand for new Schemers, like myself :)

```
; This call opens a file in the append mode (it will create a file if it doesn't exist)
(define my-file (open-file "my-file-name.txt" "a"))

; You save text to a variable
(define my-text-var1 "This is some text I want in a file")
(define my-text-var2 "This is some more text I want in a file")

; You can output these variables or just text to the file above specified
; You use string-append to tie that text and a new line character together.
(display (string-append my-text-var1 "\r\n" my-file))
(display (string-append my-text-var2 "\r\n" my-file))
(display (string-append "This is some other text I want in the file" "\r\n" my-file))

; Be sure to close the file, or your file will not be updated.
(close-output-port my-file)
```

And, for any lingering questions about the whole "\r\n" thing, please see the following answer:

[What is the difference between \r and \n?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1279779/what-is-the-difference-between-r-and-n)

Cheers!

Comment: did you test this? I believe you are missing a paren in your display statements. And As long as we are here. Why not define the text to include the newline?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the parentheses. I had this code on another machine when I wrote it, so I missed them. Concerning the "\n", sure you could put in the text string, but if you are trying to append output of a function, this makes it clearer.