# How to write to a file in append mode -scheme R5RS?

Tags: scheme, guile, r5rs

```
(call-with-output-file "b.txt"
(lambda (output-port)
(display "hello, world" output-port)))
```

How to open the b.txt in append mode. So that, my results will be appended in the text file. I have found some answer in the following. But that's not what i expect.

[Append in scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35191434/r5rs-scheme-input-output-how-to-write-append-text-to-an-output-file)

I want to work with "call-with-output-file". Since i find this properly working. With this call-with-output-file, how can i append?

Answer (score 1):

The link you mention presents a correct solution. In `guile`, the suggestion by Óscar López will not work, as its `call-with-output-file` has no `#:exists` keyword. However, this should work:

```
(let ((output-port (open-file "my.txt" "a")))
  (display "hello, world" output-port)
  (newline output-port)
  (close output-port))
```

You can find the code for `call-with-output-file` in `ice-9/boot-9`. It would be easy to extend it to support appending.